# Is OAuth possible from a Google Apps Script gadget on a site?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed a google apps script in a spreadsheet that uses oAuth.
I now copied the same script to a gadget that runs on a site. When I want to run the function that uses oauth I get the following error:

Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation

This happens both when I run the actual gadget on a site or when I run the function from the script editor. The exact same code works when called from the script editor in the spreadsheet. 
Am I doing something wrong or is it simply not possible to use oAuth with UrlFetchApp.fetch when using a site gadget?

Thanks,

Jan

Here's some sample code of what I'm trying to do, you'll need to include real api secrets from the Google Api console to test it.

```
  function CalendarApiBug( ) {

    var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService('agenda scheduler');
    oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/"+
                                   "OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
    oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
    oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('replacemewithsomethingreal');
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('replacemewithsomethingreal');

    this.baseUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/';
    this.calendarsList = null;

    this.getBaseUrl = function() {
      return this.baseUrl;
    } //CalendarApiBug.getBaseUrl

    this.getFetchArgs = function() {
      return {oAuthServiceName:'agenda scheduler', oAuthUseToken:"always"};
    } //CalendarApiBug.getFetchArgs

    this.getCalendarList = function(refresh){
      if (refresh != true && this.calendarsList != null )
        return this.calendarsList;

      var fetchArgs = this.getFetchArgs();   
      fetchArgs.method = 'get';
      var url = this.baseUrl + 'users/me/calendarList'; 
      this.calendarsList = Utilities.jsonParse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText());
      return this.calendarsList; 
    } //CalendarApiBug.getCalendarList
  }

  function test(){
    var api = new CalendarApiBug();
    Logger.log(api.getCalendarList(false));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The oAuth approval dialog only becomes visible when running the code from inside the Script Manager.  In order to publish your Apps Script code to a Site, you would have needed to publish that version of the script as a service.  Open the code editor for that script and make sure that you can run the functions with the script editor first.  This will verify your oAuth approval has been stored.

Comment: I tried running the functions in the editor first but it gives the error. I think the script is already published since the gadget's UI is shown on my site. It works as long as I don't call the oauth code.

Answer (score 0):

Why use Oauth in a Google Apps Script for the Calendar service?

Comment: Because the calendar api available through oauth allows more than the build in API, like changing the ACL of the calendar.